# Is it possible with MySQL to search for a value and with its results use those to complete the search in one statement?

Tags: mysql, node.js

A little confused with how I'd do this at all in a single statement. If it's possible?

| name | type | domain | ip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Donny | 0 | goto.com | 10.0.0.2 |
| Donny | 0 | goto2.com | 10.0.0.3 |
| Donny | 1 | null | 10.0.0.4 |
| Donny | 2 | null | 10.0.0.5 |
| Donny | 1 | null | 10.0.0.6 |
| Lisa | 0 | goto2.com | 10.0.0.3 |
| Lisa | 1 | null | 10.0.0.4 |
| Lisa | 2 | null | 10.0.0.5 |

I would like to have my Virtual Machine@ 10.0.0.5 to see it belongs to Donny and Lisa, and the returned result would be their server domains (type 0).

I can achieve this with multiple statements but was curious if it could be done with single statements and with that unsure how! Appreciate any insight on this.

I think I got it working, this is what I have thus far!

```
SELECT results.domain, results.owner
FROM (
    SELECT domain, ip, owner, type
    FROM server
    WHERE owner IN (SELECT owner FROM server WHERE ip=?)
) AS results WHERE results.type=0;
```

So if I search 10.0.0.5, I am returned

| name | domain |
| --- | --- |
| Lisa | goto.com |
| Donny | goto2.com |
| Donny | goto.com |

Seems to do what I want very clean/stealthy but wondering if it can be done better than this. :|

Comment: Why the return result should be `type 0` ?

Comment: Once the server know who the owner is, they'll check the owners for type 0 servers to get their domains.

Comment: Check my answer if it helps, it is much simplier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey mate absolutely it can.

You can use the result set from 1 SQL query in the`FROM` statement of another Query.

`Select * from (Select name from 'Table' where domain = "goto.com");`

This article will take you further: https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-nested-select/

You can also use nested SQL in the `WHERE` clause too

Comment: That's actually neat, it's a little confusing; I may need to check a few examples out.

Comment: yeah, it's really powerful! don't forget to vote and tick the correct answer :)

Comment: It's a good start but not sure if it's what I'm looking for fully. Was hopeful to do an IP search and with that result search all the names they belong to for their domain names and return that value. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM server WHERE server.ip=?) AS test ` is so far what I have but seeing quickly I cannot do it this way :P

Comment: Your last edit on your Question is correct! you got it! this looks very clean and is super readable, good job!

Comment: I was getting stuck with re-using the previous searches, it's a light load for my app (runs once on server boot ups/etc).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment you can use this two methods (maybe there are other methods).

A. You can use subquery for the names

```
select name,type,domain
from test_tbl 
where name in ( select name 
                from test_tbl 
                where ip='10.0.0.5')
and type='0';
```

B. You can use inner join but in this case, I do not recommend it.

```
select t1.name,t1.type,t1.domain
from test_tbl t1
inner join
(
  select name,type 
  from test_tbl 
  where ip='10.0.0.5'
) t2 on t1.name=t2.name
and t1.type='0';
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/123

Comment: That's much cleaner than my solution, less selects. I'll thumbs this up it's incredible.

Comment: @blanknamefornow I'm glad it helped